# jszip is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, webpack-5, jszip

in jszip library i receive `jszip is not a constructor` this error;

im using create-react-app, i changed webpack configuration to resolve :

> "webpack 5 no longer do `auto-polyfilling` for node core modules"

**Thank you for your guidance**

> npm install @craco/craco --save

> npm install crypto-browserify --save

create an `craco.config.js` in root :

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
        "fs": false,
        "tls": false,
        "net": false,
        "path": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "stream": false,
        "crypto": false,
        "crypto-browserify": require.resolve('crypto-browserify')
      };

      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
};
```